# how to get Shopify cart data using php API?

Tags: php, reactjs, shopify-app

im trying to create public Shopify App, using [Shopify / shopify-app-template-php](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-php) ,
im stuck at one place, on how to get current cart data using API.

i have tried code like below,

Routes
`Route::get('/api/get-cart-data',       [App\Http\Controllers\FormController::class, 'fetchCart']);`

FormController

```
`<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Shopify\Auth\OAuth;
use Shopify\Clients\Rest;    
use Shopify\ShopifyClient;
use Shopify\Rest\AdminApi;
use Shopify\Rest\Serialize\JsonSerializer;
use Shopify\Rest\Admin2023_04\ScriptTag;
use Shopify\Utils;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;


class FormController extends Controller
{ 
    public function fetchCart()
    {
        $shopDomain = 'myshop.myshopify.com';
        $accessToken = 'shpat0dfe2de8c1c791a9a8e2c7a2de9a5901';
        $storePassword = '123456'; 

        // Set up the API endpoint
        $url = "https://{$shopDomain}/cart.js";

        // Send the request to Shopify
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token' => $accessToken,
            'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token' => $storePassword,
        ])->get($url);    

        // Debugging statements
        //var_dump($response->status()); // status 200
        //var_dump($response->body());   // response body 11483

        // Check if the request was successful
        if ($response->successful()) {
            // Get the cart data from the response body
            $cartData = $response->json();

            // Return the cart data as a JSON response
            return response()->json($cartData);
        } else {
            // Handle the error case
            $errorMessage = $response->json()['errors'][0] ?? 'Unknown error occurred.';
            return response()->json(['error' => $errorMessage], $response->status());
        }
    }
}`
```

Reactjs Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Toast, Form, FormLayout, TextField, Select, Frame } from '@shopify/polaris';
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@shopify/polaris';
import { useAppQuery } from "../hooks";


export function GetCart() {

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCartData1 = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/get-cart-data');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Cart data:', data);        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching cart data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchCartData1();
  }, []);
}
```

but when i run the code,
its gives nothing, when i checkl with

```
var_dump($response->status()); gives status 200
var_dump($response->body());   gives response body 11483
```

and aslo asked for the store password,

below screenshot display the Response of API

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0zh4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjswJ.png)

please help me with this how can i get current cart details using API?

i have treid code, that i add already in above question

Comment: please help me with this, i need help on this issue, Thanks